# GIT Permission denied

Tags: macos, ssh, git

so I was finally forced to start using Git (which I am actually happy about), but I have not really got it running yet. My system is MacOS 10.14.5.

Here is what I did so far:

1. I have downloaded Git from https://www.linode.com/docs/development/version-control/how-to-install-git-on-linux-mac-and-windows/ and installed it.
2. I ran `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and saved a key and public key in ~/.ssh
3. I got an adress and was told to run

```
git clone bla@something.de:somemore
```

The output I get from the Terminal is

```
Cloning into 'somemore'...
bla@something.de: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I read something about creating a config file, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to make sure that admin of `something.de` added your public key into their servers for `bla` user.

Comment: Came here to say this. If you have not given them your public key, your key isn't actually doing anything.